# Recording audio from Kinect using WASAPI

Tags: wpf, kinect, naudio

I've been trying to make a recording with NAudio WPF Demo App, using Kinect as a capture device ( `Bit Depth`: 32 bits, `Sample Rate`: 16 KHz, `Number of channels` : 4, `Sample Type`: IEEE float ) but I get the error "Unsupported Wave File Format". I'm aware that WASAPI is kind of limited in a sense that it can't do any resampling when capturing audio, however shouldn't the exclusive mode let the soundcard downsample at 16 KHz? I tried that, but in vain... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My experiments with WASAPI exclusive mode indicate that it is still very fussy about what WaveFormat you can use. Often lower sample rates are not supported. You also often have to specify the exact number of soundcard input channels. (e.g. it won't record mono from a stereo device). I don't know  whether the limitations come from Windows or the soundcard drivers. You may simply have to resample  after recording (e.g. using MediaFoundationResampler).